# How do I add a selected value to ice:selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I'm facing a problem with the `ice:selectOneMenu` component in Icefaces..

In more details : 
  When I fill the `SelecItems` arrayList I set an empty selcetItem at the first index in the arrayList, like that : `mainClassificationsSI.add(new SelectItem(""));`, and in My page I have the following :

```
    <ice:selectOneMenu partialSubmit="true" binding="#
        {editOutgoingBean.mainClassificationSelect}" id="mBookClass" value="#
        {editOutgoingBean.outgoing.main_Classification}" valueChangeListener="#      
        {editOutgoingBean.mainClassificationChanged}">

        <f:selectItems value="#{editOutgoingBean.mainClassificationsSI}"/>
    </ice:selectOneMenu>
```

First of all, I'm sure that the: `editOutgoingBean.outgoing.main_Classification` has value which is one of the values of selectItems in the `SelectItems` arrayList, but when the page is displayed, the Select tag select the empty value and it didn't select the value of the `main_Classification` I set before...

When I remove the first Empty `SelectItem` from the ArrayList, the Select tag will select the value that I set for `main_Classification`. Please help me find out what to do...

Comment: could you post the code that shows how your list of SelectItems is constructed?

Answer (score 1):

try this ,may help you.

```
<ice:selectOneMenu partialSubmit="true" binding="#
    {editOutgoingBean.mainClassificationSelect}" id="mBookClass" value="#
    {editOutgoingBean.outgoing.main_Classification}" valueChangeListener="#      
    {editOutgoingBean.mainClassificationChanged}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="-1" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{editOutgoingBean.mainClassificationsSI}"/>
</ice:selectOneMenu>`
```

and don't the black select item from the bean as you were doing